# How to mask part of string with * in regex

Tags: java, regex, email, replace, mask

I want to mask email adress in Java from

```
some-email@domail.com
```

to

```
s********l@domail.com
```

- mask local name without only first and last letter
and i want to number of * match amount of replaced symbols

I need some expression like

```
 /^(.)(.*)(.)@(.*)$/
```

and replace in part 2 each symbols with *

How can i do this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with `String#replaceAll`:

```
String email = "some-email@domail.com";

String masked = email.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=[^@]*?.@)", "*");
//=> s********l@domail.com
```

Comment: It is giving wrong output.we need to use replaceAll method.

Comment: can u tell me how to only shows 3 characters at the beginning only ? the rest will be mask with asterisk

Comment: @Plugie: Use: `email = email.replaceAll("(?<=.{3}).", "*");`

Comment: @anubhava thanks a lot. do you have website recommendation to learn such things like that ?

Comment: i believe this looks to be good blog for regex http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using regex pattern **(?<=.{1}).(?=[^@]*?.@)**.

Bifurcation below:

**.{1}** matches any character (except for line terminators)

**(?=[^@]*?@)***
   Match a single character not present in the list below [^@]?
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
@ matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)